# Please HELP, Where init process is declared in the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

In Linux files where init process (**the main process with pid=1**) is being declared?

I am looking for the exact file to make some changes.

Already looked in `init.h` and nothing found.

Comment: init is not a part of Linux kernel, in what file do you want to make changes?

Comment: I have changed task_struct and added an int variable, I want for init process to save 3 in that variable that's why I am looking to the file where it's declared. @ArkadiuszDrabczyk

Comment: You are probably looking for the [init/init_task.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12.2/source/init/init_task.c) source file. Exactly it defines `init_task` object. In older versions, this definition used an initializer `INIT_TASK` which was declared in `init.h`. In the newer versions the source file itself contains an initializer.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I can't find the line where it gives init a value of 1 for pid

Comment: @Tsyvarev not exactly what OP is looking for, that is not what you usually call "init" (i.e. the userspace process with PID=1), that is PID=0.

Comment: @daniel: I intentionally edited out "Please HELP" from the title of your question: it is policy of the Stack Overflow to not use these words in the title. Please, do not insist on reverting these words back. See e.g. that question on meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255196/remove-help-please-from-titles.

Comment: The init process is spawned by the very first one using `kernel_thread` function: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12.2/source/init/main.c#L687.

Comment: why they wrote: "pid = kernel_thread(kernel_init, NULL, CLONE_FS);" why not "pid=1"? @Tsyvarev plus, if I change its pid again can I write pid=2 exactly after the line you pointed to?

Comment: Pids are allocated by the `kernel_thread` function. If you want to assign pids manually, then you need to understand how that allocation works.